# How to use 2 coding keys for same struct in swift using Codable Protocol

Tags: json, swift, protocols, decoding, codable

So I was searching if I have User struct that I want to use two different APIs on it

```
struct User {
   var firstName: String
}
```

first API has the key `firstName`, second one has the key `first_Name`

Comment: The the latter really `first_Name`? Or `first_name`? The second, traditional snake_case, is far more likely. I ask because if `first_name`, then the problem is solved with single `struct` definition and by just setting the [`keyDecodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2949119-keydecodingstrategy) for the `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: If you write your own `init(from decoder: Decoder)` you can use either key if you want.

Comment: But don’t go down that road until you’ve confirmed you really have to...

Comment: @Sulthan can you explain more please

Comment: @Rob does it differ it being first_Name or first_name??

Comment: See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) for info on how to write your own custom encoders and decoders.

Comment: @Rob thank you so much , i am new to this...

Comment: Yes, `first_name` vs `first_Name` matters. With `first_name` (proper snake casing), then the `keyDecodingStrategy` can do the conversion for you and handles everything with very little code. If you have to support both `firstName` and `first_Name` with single `struct`, then you have to write custom `init(from:)` implementation, effectively manually decoding, and losing much of the benefit of `JSONDecoder`. FWIW, `firstName` and `first_name` are both well accepted standards (camelCase and snake_case, respectively) and `first_Name` is non-standard, poor design.

Comment: If this API that is using `first_Name` yours? Do you have the ability to just fix that? It’s better to use a standard convention, rather than having to program your client code around some non-standard one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A neglected approach is a [custom `keyDecodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/custom), however this requires a *dummy* `CodingKey` struct.

```
struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?
    
    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    init?(intValue: Int) { self.stringValue = String(intValue) }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom({
    let currentKey = $0.last!
    if currentKey.stringValue == "first_Name" {
        return AnyKey(stringValue: "firstName")!
    } else {
        return currentKey
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The point is to use custom `decoder`s not custom key codings!

The struct will stay the same for both:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let firstName: String
}
```

#### Camel Case Example

```
let firstJSON = #"{ "firstName": "Mojtaba" }"#.data(using: .utf8)!

let firstDecoder = JSONDecoder()

print(try! firstDecoder.decode(User.self, from: firstJSON))
```

---

#### Snace Case Example

```
let secondJSON = #"{ "first_name": "Mojtaba" }"#.data(using: .utf8)!

let secondDecoder: JSONDecoder = {
    let decoder =  JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    return decoder
}()

print(try! secondDecoder.decode(User.self, from: secondJSON))
```

<sub>Also, You can implement your own custom strategy.</sub>

So decide which decoder  (or decoding strategy) you need for each API.